# Programmatically update widget from activity/service/receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

I know it's possible, but I can't figure out a way to trigger an update of my widget from the main activity.  Isn't there some general intent I can broadcast?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

If you *are* using an `AppWidgetProvider`, you can update it this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
// Use an array and EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS instead of AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
// since it seems the onUpdate() is only fired on that:
 int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
    .getAppWidgetI‌​ds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyAppWidgetProvider.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Where do you set `widgetId`?

Comment: Does the AppWidgetProvider then execute the onUpdate() method?

Comment: @KrisB from the answer below, get the array by doing this: int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), WidgetProvider.class));

Comment: @phaethon i am also facing the same problem, and i used ur code to update app widget on activity finish, But in my case it called the onUpdate() method of widget provider class, but after that failed to call the RemoteViewsService class. My code snapshot is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523736/app-widget-issue-while-showing-list-of-images?noredirect=1#comment22016477_15523736

Comment: It call the onRecieve override method. But question is about how to call onUpdate method.

Comment: You can use a constant, no need to hardcode: `intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);`

Comment: Great answer. Since ids is required only for the sake of firing onUpdate at least in my case, I just fake an id as following:int[] ids = {0};  I obtain all the real widget IDs in my service class.

Comment: i have added the above code. it calls onUpdateMethod(), but its not refreshing the list-view with newly updated database values.

Comment: DON'T follow @gelupa comment to use R.xml.mywidget for widgetID! It is COMPLETELY wrong and just cost me 4hours of debugging!!! USE MobileMon solution to get correct widgetID

Comment: for ids: ` int widgetIDs[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(activity).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(activity, widget.class));`

Comment: Easily converted to Xamarin (C#).  Only issue was on creating the ComponentName had to use "Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MyAppWidgetProvider)).Name".

Answer (score 81):

This helped when I searched on **how to update a widget from a service/or action** (but may be possible from every Context):

```
Context context = this;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_2x1);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.my_text_view, "myText" + System.currentTimeMillis());
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Comment: I know I'm jumping in here like 6 months late.  But I agree with Andrew.  I tried the original method in this thread.  And something about how the IDs are grabbed caused it to start failing.  This method (of directly updating the fields manually) works better.  For my purposes, at least.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Dont know how you ended up with this but works fine and smooth for all the instances of my Widget. :)

Comment: this worked for me as well. I thought we would need to do broadcast and onReceive, but my requirements fit perfectly with this

Answer (score 34):

So to update an widget from an activity, you can do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DppWidget.class);
intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), DppWidget.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Works for me :)

Comment: It call the onRecieve override method. But i want how to call onUpdate method.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyWidget.class));
        MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget();
        myWidget.onUpdate(this, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this),ids);
```

Comment: Amazingly, only this little answer solved it. I still don't know the implications of instantiating the Widget class and directly calling the onUpdate method, but hey, it finally works :)

Comment: Thanks. I am testing it out now and will post feedback. Tested and confirmed working. I am wondering through, if there are different types of widgets, will it work the same? (+1 by the way for working)

Comment: i get always ids  0

Comment: This will not work on Android Oreo any workaround fix?

Answer (score 15):

In case you are working with a widget that uses a collection such as ListView, GridView, or StackView, to update the widget's items, do as follow:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.stack_view);
```

With this method  notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(), you can force the widget items to fetch any new data in real time.

Answer (score 13):

```
int widgetIDs[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), WidgetProvider.class));

for (int id : widgetIDs)
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(id, R.id.widget_view);
}
```

Comment: Requires min-api level: 11.

Comment: Awesome. You don't even have to loop, there's a version of `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` that takes an array.

Answer (score 6):

Phaethon's accepted solution in Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java)
intent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
val ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(application).getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java!!))
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Where MyAppWidgetProvider is derived from AppWidgetProvider:

```
MyAppWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to programmatically update the widget where you do not have access to YourWidgetProvider.class explicitly, e.g. from another module or library, you can capture what YourWidgetProvider.class.getName() outputs and create a constant:

```
val WIDGET_CLASS_NAME = "com.example.yourapplication.YourWidgetProvider"
```

You would then be able to use this implicitly:

```
val intent = Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)
val widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
val ids = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, WIDGET_CLASS_NAME))
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(ids, android.R.id.list)
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
context.sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I had to do like this in a fragment:

```
Application app = getActivity().getApplication();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, RQWidget.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(app).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(app, RQWidget.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example from my to-do list:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TodosAppWidget.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), TodosAppWidget.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

```
sendBrodcast(Intent(this, TodosAppWidget::class.java).apply {
  action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
  val ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(application).getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(application, TodosAppWidget::class.java))
  putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
})
```