# App Widget issue while showing list of images

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I go through the following android documentation: "App Widgets with Collections" to create a widget that shows a list of text. Everything works fine and it works just as I wanted it to work.

Now instead of showing a list of text, I want to show a list of images that are stored in an sd-card.
So how that can be done in my code that I have implemented. If anyone has some ideas on this, please help me to solve this.

**The code I wrote:**

**WidgetProvider.java**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{
    public static String EXTRA_WORD=
            "com.commonsware.android.appwidget.lorem.WORD";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) 
        {
            Intent svcIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetService.class);

            svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            RemoteViews widget=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);

            widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.words,
                    svcIntent);

            Intent clickIntent=new Intent(ctxt, LoremActivity.class);
            PendingIntent clickPI=PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(ctxt, 0,
                            clickIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.words, clickPI);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);
        }

        super.onUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

**WidgetService.java**

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService 
{
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent)
    {
        return(new WidgetDisplay(this.getApplicationContext(),
                intent));
    }
}
```

**WidgetDisplay.java**

```
public class WidgetDisplay implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory 
{
    private static final String[] items={"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Pink", "Orange"};
    private Context ctxt=null;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public WidgetDisplay(Context ctxt, Intent intent) 
    {
        this.ctxt=ctxt;
        appWidgetId=intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return(items.length);
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) 
    {
        RemoteViews row=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.row);

        row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, items[position]);

        Intent i=new Intent();
        Bundle extras=new Bundle();

        extras.putString(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_WORD, items[position]);
        i.putExtras(extras);
        row.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1, i);

        return(row);
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() 
    {
        return(null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() 
    {
        return(1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() 
    {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

**XML File**

**Widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/words"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
  android:background="@drawable/widget_frame"
/>
```

**Row.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"   
/>
```

**Widget_provider.xml**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="146dip"
  android:minHeight="146dip"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
  android:autoAdvanceViewId="@+id/words"
  android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
  android:resizeMode="vertical"
/>
```

**ScreenShots of the widget that i got**

[image]

Comment: hey try to used my code if any query then let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am used this way and work well.

Change textview to imageview in **row.xml**

```
public WidgetDisplay(Context ctxt, Intent intent) 
    {
        this.ctxt=ctxt;
        appWidgetId=intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
                setImageinView(this.ctxt);
    }

private void setImageinView(Context context) {
//read sd card and store bitmap in  arrayListBitmap;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
remoteView = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
    remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image_photo1,arrayListBitmap.get(i));
}
```

simple you have to read sd card store data in to arraylist.

set size to **getCount()**.

now set image in your imageview.

If any query then welcome.

Comment: Yep...Its working, I have two more issue, 1.If on my app i make some changes, then on exit of my app widget is not updated. I have to remove the widget from the home screen and then again add the widget, then only update is happen in the widget 2. on click of widget how can i open my app.

Comment: 1.Home screen app widget is update every 30 minute if you update manually(Refresh button) or using timer. But using timer take more battery.

Comment: Actually i want to update it on exit of my app. Suppose in my app i have three images, and on the widget i am displaying this three images. Now user open the app and delete one images. Now as soon i exit the app i want the widget update with two images. I mean i want to update widget from activity.

Comment: Same feature i used but i am using database so delete/insert the image i can fetch image and then display.

Comment: That i know, But how u update the app widget on activity finish..That where i am confused...

Comment: in my answer setImageinView() you have to fetch all image in to database.for example if you delete one image then this method call after 30 minute and find fresh record and display it.