# Update AppWidget from an Activity

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm trying to update my AppWidget from my activity.
Similar to this question:

[Programmatically update widget from activity/service/receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455123/programmatically-update-widget-from-activity/14256988#14256988)

I'm using AppWidgetManager to get the ids and send an update broadcast but it doesn't work for me.

I suspect that it's because my AppWidgetProvider is in a library project and thus under a different package than my main app.

Any ideas on how to make it work?
I tried all kind of contexts (this, getApplication() , etc.) , nothing worked.
(I don't get the ids of the widgets).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the package name of the app in component name and the full classname in the library in the class.