# Why App widget stops working after restarting laucher?

Tags: android, android-widget

Chosen answer in duplicate is **WRONG**.

It will produce NPE if the widget app restarts.

——————————

It is a **TorchWidget** app, contains 2 classes:

**class1** AppWidgetProvider

- `setOnClickPendingIntent`  to start class2
- new `RemoteViews` to set initial button icon.

**class2**   IntentService

- switch torch
- new another `RemoteViews` to switch on/off icon.

  ```
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.torch);

  if (b) {
      mSwitch(Service.this, false);
      views.setImageViewResource(R.id.Torch,R.drawable.moon_off );
      editor.putBoolean("switch", false);
  } else {
      mSwitch(Service.this, true);
      views.setImageViewResource(R.id.Torch,R.drawable.moon_on );
      editor.putBoolean("switch", true);
  }
  ```

Full Code on [Github](https://github.com/roshad/TorchWidget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restart, the restored view will be the one instantiated in `IntentService`, which is without `OnClickPendingIntent`.

To solve the problem, I should change icon **only in update function in provider** via [broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455123/programmatically-update-widget-from-activity-service-receiver/14256988).

still a question, [why the `OnClickPendingIntent` will work until launcher restart, after view is replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360852/why-onclickpendingintent-on-remoteviews-will-work-after-view-is-replaced-until-l).

Comment: Stop editing the Question/Answer, your edits deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Comment: @VishalChhodwani man I'm the owner, what are you talking about.

Comment: I am not talking about this answer(it is just to notify you), talking about last edit.