# How to handle updating a widget after downloading data then open an Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, retrofit, retrofit2

What am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on widget it should take the user to the details of that particular task which is displayed on widget. I tried with following code but nothing is happening when clicking on widget. The details class(MasterList.class) requires data which needed to fetch from network. how do i achieve this ?

1. Can i call network for data object from widget onUpdate(). Is this a bad practice ?
2. Why there is no change nor errors in logcat ? Why app is not launching ??
3. Did i made any blunder ??

   enter code here

   ```
   @Override 
    public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds)
   {
   super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
   Intent i = new Intent(context, CallNetwork.class);
   i.setAction(ACTION);
   context.startService(i); // starting service to get data from network


   Intent intent = new Intent(context, MasterListClass.class);
   while(CallNetwork.list.size()==0||CallNetwork.list.equals(null) //waiting for network call to complete

   {

   }if (CallNetwork.get(0).getName() != null) {
           this.list = CallNetwork.list;// getting data from network
       }
   intent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.object),list.get(0));
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
   intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
    R.layout.recipe_widget);
   views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, pendingIntent);
   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[0], views);}
   ```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing: "waiting for network call to complete" in the receiver 1. It is blocking the main thread 2. Waiting in a tight loop for network IO to complete is not a good practise.

Comment: What you could do is trigger an onUpdate() in the widget from the service once the data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to trigger an onUpdate() in the widget once the service has downloaded the data from the network:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
// Use an array and EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS instead of 
AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
// since it seems the onUpdate() is only fired on that:
int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
.getAppWidgetI‌​ds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), 
MyAppWidgetProvider.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

[Programmatically update widget from activity/service/receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455123/programmatically-update-widget-from-activity-service-receiver)