# Cannot Save RecyclerView Position in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have read several threads on approaches to save the position of a RecyclerView. I have implemented the below, however it does not appear to be saving the position on either screen rotation or back navigation, it simply loads back to the top of the RecyclerView:

```
 public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private static final String POLL_QUESTION = "POLL_QUESTION";
    private static final String POLL_IMAGE_URL = "POLL_IMAGE_URL";
    private static final String FILTER_ACTION = "UPDATE_WIDGET";
    private static final String POLL_ID = "POLL_ID";
    private static final String RECYCLERVIEW_STATE = "Recyclerview_State";

    private Parcelable mRecyclerViewState;
    private static Bundle mRecyclerViewBundle;

    private MyReceiver myReceiver;


    @BindView(R.id.list)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerview;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private DatabaseReference mBaseRef;
    private DatabaseReference mPollsRef;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder> mFireAdapter;


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FeedFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FeedFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FeedFragment fragment = new FeedFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poll_feed, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);


        mPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = mPrefs.edit();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mRecyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE);
        }


        mRecyclerview.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecyclerview.setSaveEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        setReceiver();

        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//        mRecyclerViewState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
//        outState.putParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE, mRecyclerViewState);
//    }

//
//
//    @Override
//    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
//        if (savedInstanceState != null){
//            mRecyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE);
//        }
//    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mRecyclerViewState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
        outState.putParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE, mRecyclerViewState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mRecyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mRecyclerViewState != null){
            mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mRecyclerViewState);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Polls");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Poll> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Poll>()
                .setQuery(query, Poll.class)
                .build();


        mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PollHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Poll model) {

                holder.mPollQuestion.setText(model.getQuestion());
                String voteCount = String.valueOf(model.getVote_count());

                //Update shared prefs with latest question
                editor.putString(POLL_QUESTION, model.getQuestion());
                editor.putString(POLL_IMAGE_URL, model.getImage_URL());
                editor.apply();

                //TODO: Investigate formatting of vote count for thousands
                holder.mVoteCount.setText(voteCount);
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(model.getImage_URL())
                        .fit()
                        .into(holder.mPollImage);

                //TODO: Cannot understand how to utilize IntentService to update widget
                //TODO: Followed this tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/20735/android-intentservice-broadcastreceiver
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
                intent.putExtra(POLL_QUESTION, model.getQuestion());
                intent.putExtra(POLL_IMAGE_URL, model.getImage_URL());

                getActivity().startService(intent);

                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String pollID = mFireAdapter.getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();

                        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.two_pane_constraint_layout) != null & getActivity().getApplication().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                            PollFragment pollFragment = PollFragment.newInstance(pollID);
                            fm.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.poll_fragment, pollFragment)
                                    .commit();
                        } else {

                            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PollHostActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra(POLL_ID, pollID);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
                    }
                });

            }


            @Override
            public PollHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.latest_item, parent, false);
                return new PollHolder(v);
            }
        };

        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mFireAdapter);
        scrollToPosition();
        mFireAdapter.startListening();
    }

    public static class PollHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mPollQuestion;
        TextView mVoteCount;
        ImageView mPollImage;
        View mView;
        String mTag;


        public PollHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mPollQuestion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.latest_item_question);
            mPollImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pollThumbNailImage);
            mVoteCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.latest_item_poll_count);
            this.mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTag(String tag) {
            this.mTag = tag;
        }

        public View getViewByTag(String tag) {
            return mView;
        }

    }

    private void setReceiver() {
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(FILTER_ACTION);
//        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    private void scrollToPosition() {
        mFireAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int pollCount = mFireAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the user is at the bottom of the list, scroll
                // to the bottom of the list to show the newly added message.
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (pollCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    mRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String poll_Question = intent.getStringExtra("broadcastMessage");

            //TODO: Update Widget - used answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455123/programmatically-update-widget-from-activity-service-receiver
            int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getContext()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getContext(), PollWidgetProvider.class));
            PollWidgetProvider pollWidgetProvider = new PollWidgetProvider();
            pollWidgetProvider.onUpdate(getContext(), AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getContext()), ids);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I am trying to save within a Fragment, that is attached to a host Activity. I have some RecyclerView functionality coded to on.Start(), which may be overriding the methods below.

I also feel I need to make a call to onPause() somewhere since the RecyclerView is located inside a Fragment.

Full code available:https://github.com/troy21688/LiveVotingUdacity

Comment: save the scroll position to instance state and scroll the recylerview to that position on resume

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you provide some code example?